# Expand $\frac{z}{(z^2 + 1)(z^2 + 4)}$ for $1 < | z | < 2$ in Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Please help.

Expand $\frac{z}{(z^2 + 1)(z^2 + 4)}$  for $1 < | z | < 2$ in Laurent series.

Comment: What are your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Express as

$$\frac1{4 z} \left (1+\frac1{z^2} \right )^{-1} \left (1+\frac{z^2}{4} \right )^{-1}$$